# How do I prove cardinality is well-defined?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I define equinumerous and cardinality in this way:

> $A$ and $B$ are equinumerous (written $A\sim B$) if there is a
>   bijection between them.
>
> We say $card(X)=card(Y)$ if $X\sim Y$.

I would like to prove the cardinality is well-defined. This is how I did (I'm using the symmetry and transitive properties):

$X\sim Y$ and $X\sim Z\implies Y\sim Z\implies card(Y)=card(Z)$.

Am I correct? Do I need to check if the concept of equinumerous is well-defined as well?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by welldefined? Do wish to show that it is an equivalence relation?

Comment: @user45150 I want to show these two notions are not ambiguous.

Comment: @user45150 I know how to prove this is an equivalence relation.

Comment: What do you mean by non ambiguous notions? It's ambiguous for me!

Comment: I guess I am confused. $\text{card}(X)=\text{card}(Y)$ if and only if there exists a bijection between $X$ and $Y$. This is a legitimate definition. You don't pick a representative for an equivalence set or any other of the usual well-definedness problems.

Comment: @user45150 so to prove the well-definedness of the cardinality I just need to show this is an equivalence relation?

Comment: The notion is well-defined already, even before you prove it is an equivalence relation. There is nothing to check. This is because the definition: "there exists a bijection" doesn't depend any choice or anything, either there is one or there isn't

Comment: What user45150 says is right. Note that as per your definition, @user42912, $card(X)$ is not an object, it doesn't equal anything. You write $card(X)=card(Y)$ merely as an abbreviation of "There exists a bijection between $X$ and $Y$". The $=$ sign is not an actual equality. It's the same when you write $\lim \limits_{n\to +\infty}(n^2+n)=+\infty$, $+\infty$ (in introductory calculus) isn't actual object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also think that when you say "$card(X)=card(Y)$ iff $X\sim Y$", you're meaning:

"Assign every set $X$ a number called $card(X)$ in such a way that $card(X)=card(Y)$ iff $X\sim Y$"

In fact, you need to prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation in order to have a good definition of this number. Later on, you define $card(X)$ for known sets as $\{1,...,n\}$ or $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, for example.

Comment: So using this definition we don't need to prove the well-definition of the finite cardinality, i.e., if there are bijections $f:I_n\to X$ and $g:\to I_m$, then $m=n$ (notation: $I_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}$)

Comment: No. You still need to prove it. In fact, this definition lets you define the cardinality of $I_n$ as $m$ (since you'd have $I_n\sim I_m$), but, on the other hand, you define the cardinality of $I_n$ as $n$, so you must prove those are equal. (PS: You missed an $X$ after the $g$).

Comment: I don't understand. We don't need to prove the well-definedness of the general concept of cardinality, but we need to prove the finite concept of cardinality? See if $X\sim I_n$ and $X\sim I_m$, then $card(X)=n$ and $card(X)=m$ in the same time, so $m=n$. I forgot to put the X after the g, thanks for reminding me.

Comment: ${\bf DEFINITION \ 1}$: For every set $I_n$, we define $card(I_n)$ as $n$. ${\bf DEFINITION\  2}$: If $I_n\sim I_m$, we define $card(I_n):=card(I_m)$, where $card(I_m)$ is defined as above. We need to prove those two notions coincide!

Comment: @DanielEscudero The discussion you give above may be a little confusing, because you do not mention what $\text{card}(X)$ actually is. For instance what happens if $X$ is infinite. I agree that the conflation of the definition of cardinality that you give and the one in the original question may be the cause of the confusion. The reason I did not mention this point of view in my comments was that it was not mentioned in the question and I did not want to add confusion, but since it is brought up we may as well develop it.

Comment: @user42912 I think what is important to remember with regards to Daniel Escudero's definition is that it is a way to associate a size, called the cardinality, to every set $X$. For this you must check that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation because if you associate the number $n$ to $X$ and $m$ to $Y$ and $X\sim Y$ you would like to be able to conclude that $n=m$.

Comment: @DanielEscudero Another thing I forgot to mention about your response is that it should probably be checked that $I_n\not\sim I_m$ if $n\neq m$. That is implicit in what your method needs for well-definedess (but not what was needed in user45150's original question)

Comment: @user45150 I appreciate your comments! You're right, I'll keep it in mind. (I hope the O.P. does it too).

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments